# C# - Readonly properties and fields cannot be set in derived class constructors

Tags: c#, constructor, derived-class, readonly-attribute

I have a class structure like the following

```
abstract class AMyAbstractClass {
    public readonly int MyReadonlyField;
    public int MyReadonlyProperty { get; }//read-only auto-property (syntactic sugar)
}
class MyConcreteClass : AMyAbstractClass {
    MyConcreteClass() {
        this.MyReadonlyField = 1;
        this.MyReadonlyProperty = 1;
    }
}
```

Which throws compilation errors

> A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a variable initializer)

And

> Property or indexer 'AMyAbstractClass.MyReadonlyProperty cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Respectively.

In the first case, the error message is erroneous, since it *is* being set in a constructor!

---

I can come up with alternative ways to have immutable object properties, but why is this situation disallowed? What are good practices for this type of encapsulation?

Comment: That first error message is perhaps a little unclear, but you just need a constructor (probably `protected` too) in the base class.

Comment: That is the verbatim error message I get in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: It is the same in both cases whether the abstract class has any constructor.

Answer (score 8):

You need to propagate them via base class' constructor:

```
abstract class AMyAbstractClass {
    public readonly int MyReadonlyField;
    public int MyReadonlyProperty { get; }//syntactic sugar
    protected AMyAbstractClass (int fieldValue, int propertyValue) {
        this.MyReadonlyField = fieldValue;
        this.MyReadonlyProperty = propertyValue;
    }
}
class MyConcreteClass : AMyAbstractClass {
    public MyConcreteClass() 
        : base(fieldValue: 1, propertyValue:1) {
    }
}
```

Regarding `readonly` fields. Reference from [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification, chapter 15.5.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=306):

> When a  field
>   - declaration includes a  readonly modifier, the fields introduced by the declaration are  readonly fields . Direct assignments to readonly
>   fields ca n only occur as part of that declaration or in an  instance
>   constructor or static constructor in the same class.

And the description for [read-only auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#read-only-auto-properties) from c# 6:

> ... properties can be set only in the body of a
>   constructor:

Comment: I would add that (except if you're doing Unity) you should really avoid public variable (even if readonly). Use your properties to access your variables

Comment: Please also try to answer the "why" part of my question.

Comment: @Elaskanator, I've put citations

Comment: Your ECMA spec article has wording "...in the same class" which indeed appears to be the case. I still do not understand *why* though. The MSDN article about auto-properties does not even indicate the limitation.
P.S. I could not remember what it was called, thank you for digging up the "Read-only auto-properties" link.

Comment: @Elaskanator, so `why in the same type's constructor only` - that makes perfect sense for me, in my opinion it's because of encapsulation, read only nature of the both cases means that **outer** code may not get them changed, even child-type constructor is an outer code here

Comment: @Elaskanator, although some years have passed and this question has been closed, the *why* you were asking for is not fully addressed. For future visitors let me add that the value of a ´readonly´ field may be hardcoded in the (probably parameterless) base constructor or even in the declaration. Allowing child classes to set the field in their constructor would be equivalent to overwriting the decisions made in the base class (obviously violating the readonly contract). In your case this might have happened intenionally. In library code exposed to others this may have unforeseen consequences.